# Over or under half price

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions, numbers

If something normally cost £300 and someone is selling exactly the same item for £100, is this:

> 1. over half price
> 2. under half price

Does it depend on context or is either correct?

For example, if I were in marketing, and had this as a deal, which would be the correct choice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We're talking about the price, not the discount.

£100 is less than half of £300, so it's **less than half-price** (or "under half price" if you prefer).

For a sale price, where a single shop reduces the price to under half, it might advertise "More than 50% off" and emphasise the size of the discount. You're less likely to see that when comparing different sellers.

Answer (score -8):

I suppose that technically it should be "Over half price", since the discount is greater than half.  However, I'd prefer to see "less than half price" or even "more than half off".

Comment: Yeah, the _discount_ is over 50%, but the _price_ is under!

Comment: Technically speaking, that's a pretty loose use of the word "technically".